# OpenSSH Server on Windows refuses logons. How do I fix?

Tags: powershell, upgrade, sshd

My OpenSSH Server denies all login attempts, returning "permission denied" regardless of keyfile, password, etc.
When started in debugging mode on the windows host, the server prints

```
PS C:\Users\someguy\Documents\PowerShell> sshd.exe -d         
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7, LibreSSL 2.6.5 
....
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user someguy service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
User domain\\someguy not allowed because shell c:\\program files\\powershell\\6\\pwsh.exe does not exist
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When installed, SSHD stores the path to a login shell executable in the registry entry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH
```

In my case, it was `c:\\program files\\powershell\\6\\pwsh.exe`

Upgrading powershell core removes the previous version, and invalidates that OpenSSH entry. To correct the problem, I edited the entry, replacing the `6` with a `7`, and restarted the sshd server. Remote access was restored.

IMHO, the Powershell installer should open a modal dialog a warning of the deletion before it proceeds.